# How to know whether the value of a key in NSDictionary is NSString or another NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdictionary

I am parsing some JSON values. I have a NSDictionary and for a certain value the object I get can either be a NSString (e.g. "USA") or a NSDictionary (e.g. 1="USA", 2="UK" etc).

Is there a way to know when the object is NSString or NSDictionary ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All classes inherited from **NSObject** class have a couple of methods to test inheritance, behavior and conformance:

```
– isKindOfClass:
– isMemberOfClass:
– respondsToSelector:
– conformsToProtocol:
```

In your case use isKindOfClass: method:

```
if ([someObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {...}
if ([someObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {...}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to test that using isKindOfClass.

For example:

```
NSObject *object = [dict objectForKey:@:"key"];
if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
{
  // it's a string
}
else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
{
  // it's a dictionary
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`isKindOfClass:` message is your friend:

```
id value = [dict objectForKey@"foo"];

BOOL isString = [value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]];
BOOL isDict = [value iskindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]];

NSLog(@"is string:%i\tis dictionary:%i", isString, isDict);
```

Reference material: [NSObject Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html)